# Install app once debugged

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

I want to keep the app installed in my phone once I run it in **Android Studio**, normally the app run in my phone but  when I look for it on my phone It doesn't show up.
I think I'm missing something at the manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

For your main activity make sure you have the following intent filters in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: IMHO the most logical answer ... among all other answers

Answer (score 0):

Get Drop Box.

Install Drop Box on your phone.

Run the app at least one time.

Upload the apk file (\\build\outputs\apk)

Install apk from dropbox

Or

Use adb by:

adb install C:\package.apk – Installs the package located at C:\package.apk on your computer on your device.

For reference check here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build/Build APK it will release an apk in some folder. and just copy it to your sdcard or storage.

Comment: I did it, I used the generated apk to install my app, BUT It doesn't show up on my phone... any help ? I think is something in my code that is wrong, probably a line that makes my app executable or somehing.

Comment: There will be two versions of the app which one are you installing ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the app in an emulator, the apk should build be in the specified folder. See if that works